# React Firestore how to create a unique url when posting document to firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Not sure where to start on this one, so here goes.

After creating a document in Firestore by POSTing data the user inputs in my React application state, how can I create a unique URL that a user can visit to GET/view that data?

For example:

https://myreactwebsite.com/new-document/

I need to ensure that a unique URL exists in my website index, so that not only can a user visit, but it can be indexed by Google for SEO.

My React application is hosted on Firebase as well as using Firestore for the database.

Answer (score 1):

Firestore is a NoSQL Document database (Much like MongoDB if you're familiar with it). They both implement some form of document ID in each document. That could be leveraged in creating a unique route in your use case.

I would create a route such as `/profile/:id` in your react app, that when you visit it you make a call to your backend requesting that profile and then use the response from that request to fill in the data.

I would try to describe it here but in all honesty, [this page does a much better](https://learnwithparam.com/blog/dynamic-pages-in-react-router/) job than I could in one short SO post

Comment: @mav91 *Firestore is effectively an implementation of MongoDB* - is not accurate. They are totally separate, unrelated databases from two different companies with different API's and SDK's as well as a different overall approach to NoSQL. That being said, this *use the unique ID from that document as the route* is a great suggestion. When a document is created in Firestore, if you don't supply the documentId, a unique documentId is generated which could be used in the url. See the [DocumentSnapshot API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#id)

Comment: You are 100% correct. I was wrong to say that it is an implementation of it. I will adjust my statement to them both being document databases which both employ unique document Ids in their formation so we don't cast anyone off the beaten path in the future.

Comment: @Abe the article is helpful and a good start, but I'm still unsure how I apply it to routes that fetch data from Firestore. For instance how do I create a dynamic route to request the data for each user in my Firestore database? I've been reading up on it all day for some reason i'm struggling to understand this concept.

Comment: Mav, I'm pretty free today. It's been forever since I've used React but I can fire up my editor and I can send you some samples of what I'm talking about. If there's another method you'd prefer to learn please let me know.

Comment: @mav91 I've created a github repo showing how something like this would be implemented. The only file relevant is just App.js message me on github if you have questions

https://github.com/AbeMoe/react-dynamic-routing

Comment: Thanks @Abe I will check this out tomorrow:)

Comment: @Abe - the first two blocks of code make sense, where you use Axios to grab the data, then map over the array within the Router, the last block I'm not so sure on

Comment: Mav91, I added some comments and suggestions to that particular code block. Let me know if you have any more questions!